# Is the set of all polynomials in $\log(x)$ dense in $L^2[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis

Is $\{(\log(x))^k\mid k=0,1,2,\ldots\}$ dense in $L^2 [0,1]$? That is, is the set of all polynomials of logarithm functions dense in the set of square integrable functions on $[0,1]$?

Comment: @Fabian I think the OP is asking wether the linear span of the polynomials is dense in $L^2$. The fact that they all vanish at $0$ (except for $k=0$ btw) is of no consequence since we are working in $L^2$.

Comment: How do you evaluate your $(\log(x))^k$ at $0$? You seem to work on the closed interval $[0,1]$ after all...

Comment: @mkl The space $L^2$ consists of equivalence classes of functions; pointwise evaluation is not defined for elements of $L^2$.

Comment: @Pavel you're right, of course. I was led somewhat astray by remarks of the functions vanishing at 0, a single point, after all.

Answer (score 6):

Let's change the variable: $x=e^{-t}$, $t> 0$. This induces an isometry between $L^2([0,1])$ and the weighted Lebesgue space $L^2((0,\infty),e^{-t})$. The polynomials in $\log x$ become polynomials in $t$. We may decide to orthonormalize them with respect to the weight $e^{-t}$, thus obtaining [Laguerre polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials). The question can now be restated as: do the Laguerre polynomials form a basis of $L^2((0,\infty),e^{-t})$? Interestingly, I could not find an answer to this obvious question in the Wikipedia article, or [Mathworld article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LaguerrePolynomial.html), or in [Springer EOM](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Laguerre_polynomials). At last a Google search brought up [this paper](http://www.mat.ucm.es/serv/revmat/vol19-2/vol19-2i.pdf) where this statement is made explicitly:

> It is known that $\{L_n\}$ is a basis in $L^2(0,\infty)$ with respect to the measure $e^{-x}\,dx$ (see, e.g., [6, p. 349]).
>
> [6] G. Sansone, Orthogonal functions, rev. English ed., Dover Publications Inc., New York, 1991.

Comment: Another reference: [On the completeness of the generalized Laguerre polynomials](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/100461/79365).

Comment: cf. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100461/on-the-completeness-of-the-generalized-laguerre-polynomials

Answer (score 0):

**This is not an answer** (and possibly total nonsense), but it's too long for a comment. Let $V=\operatorname{Vect}(1,\log,\log^2,\dots)$, and suppose we wanted to show it is dense (which I suspect). We only need to show that its orthogonal is $0$.

We could try working with a Hilbert basis. I don't know how to calculate the integrals of a cosine/sine-function against $\ln^q$. However, for $p,q\in\mathbb{N}$:
$$\langle t^p,\log^q\rangle=\frac{(-1)^q q!}{(p+1)^{q+1}}$$
Because continuous maps are dense in $L^2[0,1]$ and continuous functions can be uniformly approximated using polynomials, polynomials are dense in $L^2$. Suppose $f\perp V$, and $f\neq 0$. *There should be* real numbers $c_n,~n\in\Bbb N$ with $f=\sum_{n\in \Bbb N} c_n t^n$ in $L^2$ (which strikes me as perfectly unbelievable). *If* this holds, letting $c_N$ be the first non-zero coefficient, we'd *probably* get $$0=\langle f,\ln^q\rangle\sim c_N\frac{(-1)^q q!}{(N+1)^{q+1}}$$ which would be contradictory, and so $V$ would be dense.

Any input appreciated!

Comment: Seems like a case for [Stone-Weierstrass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone-Weierstrass_theorem) to show first that the linear span if the logarithms is dense in $C[\varepsilon,1]$, which is enough.

Comment: @Martin I'm not approximating the logarithms, but continuous funtions on $[0,1]$.

Comment: So am I :-) $ $

Comment: @Martin sorry, I might have misunderstood your comment. Do you mean to say that we can first show that the polynomials in $\ln$ can approximate a continuous funtion on $[\epsilon,1]$?

Comment: Yes: the polynomials in ln contain the constants and they separate the points on $[\varepsilon,1]$ and they are an algebra, so Stone Weierstrass tells us they are uniformly dense in $C[\varepsilon,1]$ (for real scalars).

Comment: @Martin you are right. Is this enough to show that they are dense in $L^$? I can easily see that the union of the $C[\epsilon,1]$ is dense, but the problem I see is that the logarithms extend unboundedly to a neighbourhood of $0$, while the continuous functions don't.

Comment: You are right, one needs to be careful about the tail ends on $[0,\varepsilon]$ that explode with the degree of the polynomial. Maybe there was a bit too much wishful thinking on my part...