# Meaning of $\alpha$ in Laguerre polynomials

Tags: special-functions, approximation, orthogonal-polynomials, approximation-theory

I found that generalized Laguerre polynomials are:

$$ L_n^{\alpha} (x) = \sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i {n+\alpha \choose n-i} \frac{x^i}{i!}.$$

However, I wonder what is the meaning of $\alpha$ in this expression. How does influence in the polynomial?

I know that it may shift it because if we evaluate it int $x=0$, we get

$$L_n^{\alpha}(0)= {n+\alpha\choose n} \approx \frac{n^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha+1)}.$$

But, do these polynomials still converge using the Least Square approximant if $\alpha \neq 0$??

**EDIT**: this last question is referring to use Laguerre series to approximate a function $f(x)$ by

$$f_m = \displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^m c_k L_k^{\alpha}(x),$$

where $c_k$ are the fourier coefficients of Laguerre:

$$c_k = \langle f,L_k^{\alpha}\rangle = \displaystyle\int_0^{\infty} f(x) L_k^{\alpha}\,w(x) dx,$$

and $w(x)$ is the corresponding weight function, namely

$$w(x)=x^{\alpha}e^{-x}.$$

I know that this $f_m$ converges to $f$ when $\alpha=0$, my question is if it does for other cases.

Comment: You may see $\alpha$ as a parameter that can change a number of things: the asymptotic distribution and such. The [Wikipedia article][1] gives many results: some on the distribution and some on the derivatives of the polynomials depending on the value of $\alpha$ (whether it is integer or $0$). I am sure if you dig deep enough you can find a more satisfying answer, the generalised Laguerre polynomials and related polynomials/transforms have a lot of coefficients as these are the coefficients in specific DE's that are used to define them.
[1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Very* roughly speaking: Laguerre polynomials look like the family of trigonometric functions ($\sin nx$ or $\cos nx$) in the region where the weight is concentrated. That is, they have moderate size and slowly increasing oscillation with $n$. Outside of this region, they look pretty much like any random collection of polynomials.

When $\alpha=0$, the weight $e^{-x}$ is concentrated near $0$. On the graph below the weight is shown in black, and the first five Laguerre polynomials $L_n$ are in various colors. You can see that they look like $1-\sin nx$ near $0$, and then wildly diverge when the weight becomes small.

[image: L_n]

For comparison, I did the same with $\alpha=2$. The polynomials have civilized appearance where the weight is not too small, roughly in the interval $[1,4]$. They wildly diverge both to the  left and to the right.

[image: L_n^2]

> do these polynomials still converge  using the Least Square approximant

When $\alpha=0$, the Laguerre polynomial form on *orthonormal* basis of $L^2([0,\infty),e^{-x})$ ([reference here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/271151/79365)). Therefore, for any function $f\in L^2([0,\infty),e^{-x})$ we have $\sum c_n L_n\to f$ in the norm, where $c_n=\langle f,L_n\rangle$.

When $\alpha>0$,  the Laguerre polynomial form on *orthogonal* (but [not normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials#Orthogonality)) basis* of $L^2([0,\infty),x^\alpha e^{-x})$. Therefore, for any function $f\in L^2([0,\infty),x^\alpha e^{-x})$ we have $\sum c_n L_n^{(\alpha)}\to f$ in the norm, where $c_n=\langle f,L_n^{(\alpha)}\rangle / \|L_n^{(\alpha)}\|$. (The value of $\|L_n^{(\alpha)}\|$ is given on Wikipedia).

(*) Disclaimer: I don't have a reference for the the completeness of $\{L_n^{(\alpha)}\}$, but I just put a bounty on unanswered question [On the completeness of the generalized Laguerre polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/100461/) in the hope someone does. Or you can consult  the books G. Polya *Orthogonal polynomials* and  G. Sansone *Orthogonal functions*, in case they treat $L_n^{(\alpha)}$.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the graphs.

I mean, if we user Laguerre series to approximate a function $f(x)$ by $f_m = \displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^m c_k L_k^{\alpha}(x)$, where $c_k$ are the fourier coefficients of Laguerre: $c_k = \langle f,L_k^{\alpha}\rangle = \displaystyle\int_0^{\infty} f(x) L_k^{\alpha}\,w(x) dx$ and $w(x)$ is the corresponding weight function, namely $w(x)=x^{\alpha}e^{-x}$. I know that this $f_m$ converges to $f$ when $\alpha=0$, my question is if it does for other cases.

Comment: What I get is not that the Laguerre polynomials oscillate less or more... what I get is that are shifted, that is why from your graphs seem that are more spaced in the x=0.

Comment: @Kits89 I added an answer to your convergence question.

Comment: @Kits89 The question [On the completeness of the generalized Laguerre polynomials](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/100461/79365) now has a nice answer with exposition of completeness and multiple references. You may find it interesting (it deserves more upvotes than it currently has).