# Set of finite linear combination is dense in $L^2(0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

This exercise is from Rudin's Real and Complex analysis at chapter 15, problem 22.

> $A=\{ f_{n} = t^n exp(-t)\}$ where $(0 \leq t \leq \infty, n \in \mathbb{N}).$ Prove that $A$ is dense in $L^{2}(0,\infty)$.
>
> Hint : If $g \in L^{2}(0,\infty)$ is orthogonal to each $f_n$ and if $F(z) = \int_{0}^{\infty}exp(-tz)\overline{g(t)}dt,$ (Re $z>0$), then all derivatives of $F$ are $0$ at $z=1$. Consider $F(1+yi)$.

I understand the hint want me to use Hanh-Banach theorem, but I don't know how the $F(z)$ is related with the theorem. Even if I accept $F'(1)=0$, what can I do that? Could you give me more hints to approach this problem?

Edit: Thank you for all of you. I'll give a try for solving problem.

Let $g \in L^{2}(0,\infty)$ is orthogonal to each $f_n,$ e.g. $\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{n}e^{-t}\overline{g(t)}dt = 0$ for all $n=0,1,2, \cdots$. Define $F(z) = \int_{0}^{\infty}\exp(-tz)\overline{g(t)}dt$ where Re $z >0$.

1) F is well-defined since $(\int_{0}^{\infty}|exp(-tz)|^{2}dt)^{1/2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 Re z}} <\infty$, so $e^{-tz}$, $g(t)$ are in $L^{2}$.

2) $F^{(n)}(w) = \int_{0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}t^n e^{-tz} \overline{g(t)}dt$

since $\lim_{z \to w}\frac{F(z) - F(w)}{z-w} = \lim_{z \to w} \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-tz}-e^{-tw}}{z-w}\overline{g(t)}dt $

and this part is what I do not know how to deal with, but I think I can apply dominated convergence theorem or any other theorem, to derive that

$\lim_{z \to w} \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-tz}-e^{-tw}}{z-w}\overline{g(t)}dt =  \int_{0}^{\infty}\lim_{z \to w} \frac{e^{-tz}-e^{-tw}}{z-w}\overline{g(t)}dt= \int_{0}^{\infty}-te^{-tz}\overline{g(t)}dt$, and by repeating such differentiating, we get desired result.

3) $F^{(n)}(1) = 0$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}\cup \{0\}$ since $F^{(n)}(1)$ is just $<f_{n},g>$, which is 0 by assumption.

4) So $F$ is holomorphic on half plane where real part is greater than 0, and $F$'s power series representation at $z=1$ implies $F \cong 0$.

So, if we think $0= F(1+iy)$ for $y\in \mathbb{R}$, $F(i+y) = \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t}\overline{g(t)}e^{-iyt}dt$, a Fourier transform of $e^{-t}\overline{g(t)}$, call $\mathbb{F}(e^{-t}\overline{g(t)}$. Hence by fourier inversion formula, $e^{-t}\overline{g(t)} = \int_{0}^{\infty}\mathbb{F}(e^{-t}\overline{g(t)}e^{iyt} = \int 0 dt =0$. So $e^{-t}\overline{g(t)} \cong 0$. But $e^{-t}\neq 0$ for any $t \in (0,\infty)$, $g(t) = 0$ almost everywhere.

5) Conclusion : so any function which is not spanned by closure of span$\{f_n \}$ is zero almost everywhere. Hence the span is dense.

Re-question : You know that my proof was not completed, especially on interchanging limit and integral when I calculate $F^{(n)}$. Could you give some more idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only the first derivative, but also the evaluation and all higher derivatives are zero: $F(1)=F'(1)=F''(1)=\ldots=0.$ This implies that $F(z)$ is identically zero on its domain.

Now the last part of the hint invites you to write out $F(1+yi)$. For $y$ running through $\mathbb R$ this is actually a Fourier transform and by Fourier inversion $g$ must be zero almost everywhere on the positive reals.

Comment: What is $g?\,\,$

Comment: A hypothetical squarely integrable function class that is not in the closed span of the functions $f_n$

Comment: Yes, sorry, it's right there in the hypotheses.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you. I will post my own answer this afternoon (GMT+9)

Comment: @Justpassingby I posted my answer by editing this post. It would be helpful for me to get your comment on the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Looks legit from here, I will think about the dominated convergence. Meanwhile perhaps note that the Fourier transform operaters on functions of all real numbers, not just the positive reals, so you might want to throw in an indicator function $1_{(0,\infty)}(t)$

Comment: But then, it remains to prove that $F^{(n)}(1)=0$ for $n\geq 0$ implies that $F(z)\equiv 0$ for $\Re(z)>0$, right? I know it is right and it is well-known in the community of harmonic analysis. But how to prove this statement in an elementary way?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach. If we define [Laguerre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials) through the [Rodrigues formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues_formula#Rodrigues_formula):
$$ L_n(x) = \frac{e^x}{n!}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left(x^n e^{-x}\right) $$
we have:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty} L_n(x)L_m(x)e^{-x}\,dx = \delta(n,m) $$
by integration by parts, hence Laguerre polynomials give an orthogonal base of $L^2(0,+\infty)$ with the inner product $\langle f,g\rangle = \int_{0}^{+\infty}f(x)g(x)e^{-x}\,dx$. The leading term of $L_n(x)$ is just $\frac{(-1)^n x^n}{n!}$ and the previous base [is a complete base](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100461/on-the-completeness-of-the-generalized-laguerre-polynomials). Rudin's claim easily follows.

Answer (score 1):

By convergence dominated theorem, the limit and integral commutes. Hint: you may use the following inequality to dominate the function sequence:
\begin{equation*}
|\exp(z)-z-1|\leq\frac{|z|^2\exp(|z|)}{2},\quad z\in \mathbb{C}.
\end{equation*}