# completeness of Laguerre polynomials

Tags: functional-analysis, orthogonal-polynomials

Can you help me to prove that system of Laguerre polynomials
$$ L_n = \dfrac{e^t}{n!}\dfrac{d^n}{dt^n} (t^n e^{-t})$$ is completeness in space $L_2((0, \infty),e^{-t}dt)$ ?

i have idea of proof:
system is complete if
for $x\in H$ fair equalities $(x,e_n)=0$ $\forall n$, then $x=0$
i.e.
$\int_0^\infty x(t)L_ndt =0$,  I can not integrate this integral, can you help me with this?

Comment: Take $\alpha=0$ in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/417870 which is devoted to **generalized** Laguerre polynomials